# Quick Question about Representation of Elements in $\operatorname{Span}(S)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and let $S \subset X$ be a nonempty subset of $X$. We know that $\operatorname{span}(S)$ is the set of all linear combination of vectors in $S$.

If $x_0 \in \operatorname{Span}(S)$, then $x_0 = c_1 s_1 + \cdots + c_n s_n$ for some scalars $c_i \in \mathbb{F}$ and vectors $s_i \in S$.

Now suppose $x_1 \in \operatorname{Span}(S)$ and is different from $x_0$. My question is about the representation of $x_1$. In the first scenario, would the same vectors $s_1,\dotsc,s_n$ used in the representation of $x_0$ be used in the linear combination of $x_1$ where only some of the scalars are different? That is, $x_1 = d_1 s_1 + \cdots + d_n s_n$ for some scalars $d_i$?

Or would both the scalars and possibly the vectors in the linear combination of $x_1$ be different, say $x_1 = d_1 s^{\star}_1 + \cdots + d_m s^{\star}_m$?

I'm leaning towards the latter, but I"m not entirely sure. The two texts that I've looked at both begin with a list of vectors $v_1,\dotsc,v_n$, and then talk about the span of that list, but not an arbitrary set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working in a finite dimensional vector space $X$, or even if $\mathrm{Span}(S)$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $X$, then you can find a finite basis for $\mathrm{Span}(S)$ made up of vectors $s_{1}, \ldots, s_{k} \in S$; then you can write any vector in $\mathrm{Span}(S)$ as a linear combination of these same vectors, that is you can guarantee that
$$x_{0} = d_{1}s_{1} + \cdots + d_{k}s_{k}$$
$$x_{1} = d_{1}^{\prime}s_{1} + \cdots + d_{k}^{\prime}s_{k}$$
(where some of the coefficients may be zero).

If $\mathrm{Span}(S)$ is not finite dimensional, then the normal convention is that the elements of $\mathrm{Span}(S)$ is taken to be the set of linear combinations of elements of $S$ (which have a finite number of terms), in this case you cannot guarantee that each vector in the span will use the same vectors of $S$ in their representation.